# Rails 4 : how to use UNIX_TIMESTAMP with group YEAR

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, timestamp, xslt-grouping

I have the following code

```
Call.group('YEAR(created_at)').count
```

Which returns

```
{2013=>81577, 2012=>93323, 2011=>79915, 2010=>59084, 2009=>55561}
```

How can I use `UNIX_TIMESTAMP` for the years so that the `UNIX_TIMESTAMP` value is returned (ex. `1356912000000`) instead of the year (ex. `2013`) ?

I tried

```
Call.group('UNIX_TIMESTAMP(YEAR(created_at))').count
```

But it didn't work.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`unix_timestamp()` expects a date/datetime argument and returns an int. `year()` returns an integer, so you're going to be doing an invalid operation. You'd need to do something like

```
UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CONCAT(YEAR(created_at), '-01-01 00:00:00'))
```

which would evaluate to

```
UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2013-01-01 00:00:00')
```

and give you the timestamp for the beginning of the year.

Answer (score 0):

probably a better way to do this - but it should work

```
counts = {}
# NOTE: could be off by a few records near the end of the year due to timezones
raw_counts = Call.group('YEAR(created_at)').count

raw_counts.each do |key, value|
  # rebuild the hash key
  # convert date to first day of the year
  # use to_i on the date to get unix timestamp
  counts[Time.zone.parse("#{key}-01-01").to_i] = value
end
```

counts.inspect

```
{ 
  1293840000 => 221794, 
  1325376000 => 239135, 
  1356998400 => 293378 
}
```